# Basic antd example rendering a blank page

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm trying to create the most basic react app using antd but it renders a blank page. I used a venv, ran `npx create-react-app .` and replaced the default App.js file contents with the below example from the [antd website](https://ant.design/docs/react/use-with-create-react-app). Can someone please advise?

App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button } from 'antd';
import 'antd/dist/reset.css';
import './App.css';

const App = () => (
  <div className="App">
    <Button type="primary">Button</Button>
  </div>
);

export default App;
```

Terminal output:

```
Compiled successfully!

You can now view antd-examples in the browser.

  Local:            http://localhost:3000
  On Your Network:  http://10.5.0.2:3000

Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, use npm run build.

webpack compiled successfully
```

I was expecting to see a button show up with the above code given there were no errors or warnings but just saw a blank screen instead. Note that when I use the starter code generated from running `npx create-react-app .`  the page renders fine and I see the slowly rotating react symbol.

Edit:

1. There is some messages in the console log. You can see it here in [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/YXvfyMsX).
2. The package.json file contents are here on [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/P81fHiQR).

Comment: what if you remove the ticks around `'<Button type="primary">Button</Button>'`

Comment: Just removed it as I saw your comment. Still no change.

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the dev console of your browser?

Comment: Could you maybe post your `package.json` as well?

Comment: Yes, I have now added both package.json and console output to the post.

Comment: I think you forgot to install the `antd` dependency with `yarn add antd`?

Comment: that did the trick, thank you! If you make that an answer, I can accept it

Comment: No problem at all :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in this case is that the `antd` dependency is missing in the `package.json`. After installing it with `yarn add antd` the code works like expected.